# Can access data from Node/MongoDB in browser but not in Postman - is this a CORS issue?

Tags: node.js, cors, postman, backend

I'm testing a Node.js back end, which connects to MongoDB.

The Node/MonogoDB connection is fine - when I enter `http://localhost:3000/stories` in the browser it shows the response with data from the DB.

But when testing on Postman, nothing comes back: `Error: CORS request rejected: http://localhost:3000/stories`

Here's the controller:

```
const { getCollection } = require('./service/DatabaseService')
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb')

const handleOptionsRequest = async (request, response) => {
    response.status(200).send()
}

const getStory = async (request, response) => {
    const collection = await getCollection("Project", "Collection")
    let data = await collection.find({}).toArray()
    console.log(data)
    return response.status(200).json({
        message: "Successfully retrieved story",
        data: data,
    })
}

module.exports = { getStory, handleOptionsRequest }
```

and index.js

```
const { routes } = require('./routes.js')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(function (request, response, next) {
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET", "OPTIONS")
  next()
})

routes(app)

app.listen(port)
```

I tried logging the variables, request and response to the terminal.

When Postman is sending its request to Node, the function in the controller runs and does log the data from the DB to the terminal.

But it can't get through to Postman!

Any ideas?

Comment: It is definitely a `cors` issue.

Comment: If you want to allow `cors` then  install the cors package and use `app.use(cors( ))`. Assuming you have setup like `const app=http.createserver( )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a `cors` issue. If you want to allow `cors` then install cors package using `npm i cors` and then use `app.use(cors())`.

```
const express = require('express')
const cors= require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())
app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
// Do something here, send response
});
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: Remember it is only for testing, use it only if your app specifically requires it. Using cors is a bad idea otherwise.

Comment: Check this link for more details : https://stackabuse.com/handling-cors-with-node-js/